# Import Pivottable js in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pivottable.js

I'm learning Angular 2 and trying to import nicolas kruchten's Pivottable js in an angular 2 application

When I'm trying to wrap pivottable js in the angular 2 It is not giving any error however when I try to check the same in the browser It is not displaying the Pivot table.

I can check that the component is created but is always empty.

I think `AfterViewInit` should let me display table.

\\ pivot.component.ts

```
import {Component , Inject, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;
import 'pivottable/dist/pivot.min.js';
import 'pivottable/dist/pivot.min.css';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pivot',
  template: `<div id="pivot"></div>`
})

export class PivotWrapper {

private el: ElementRef;
//constructor spelling was incorrect now working fine
constructor (@Inject(ElementRef)el: ElementRef){
    this.el = el;
}
ngAfterViewInit(){

    if (!this.el ||
        !this.el.nativeElement ||
        !this.el.nativeElement.children){
            console.log('cant build without element');
            return;
    }

    var container = this.el.nativeElement;
    var inst = jQuery(container);
    var targetElement = inst.find('#pivot');

    if (!targetElement){
        console.log('cant find the pivot element');
        return;
    }

    //this helps if you build more than once as it will wipe the dom for that element
    while (targetElement.firstChild){
        targetElement.removeChild(targetElement.firstChild);
    }

    //here is the magic
    targetElement.pivot([
            {color: "blue", shape: "circle"},
            {color: "red", shape: "triangle"}
        ],
        {
            rows: ["color"],
            cols: ["shape"]
        });
}
```

}

\\ app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ElementRef,Inject} from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;
import {PivotWrapper} from './pivot.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

\\ app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {PivotWrapper} from './pivot.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, PivotWrapper
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, PivotWrapper]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I don't see how AfterViewInit is used. I presume it should be implemented and call buildPivot() , is that correct?

Comment: @cmonkey It was a silly mistake, as the spelling for constructor was incorrect.
But now when I try using `pivotUI` function it gives rendering error

Comment: This is an example of using react with pivottable https://github.com/kurtzace/pivottableandreact (read as pivottobale working in a typescipt ecosystem) - may not answer your question - but may give you hints

Answer (score 3):

Please see below for the solution:
I am using angular cli

**--package.json**

```
 "jquery": "^3.2.1",
 "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",    
 "pivottable": "^2.13.0",
```

**--angular-cli.json**

```
 "styles": [
     "../node_modules/pivottable/dist/pivot.min.js",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
  "../node_modules/pivottable/dist/pivot.min.js"

  ],
```

**--app-pivot-wrapper**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject, ElementRef, AfterViewInit }   from '@angular/core';

import 'pivottable/dist/pivot.min.js';
import 'pivottable/dist/pivot.min.css';
declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;

@Component({
selector: 'app-pivot-wrapper',
templateUrl: './pivot-wrapper.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./pivot-wrapper.component.css']
})

export class PivotWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
private el: ElementRef;
constructor(@Inject(ElementRef)el: ElementRef) { 
   this.el = el;

 }

 ngOnInit() {      
}

ngAfterViewInit(){

if (!this.el ||
    !this.el.nativeElement ||
    !this.el.nativeElement.children){
        console.log('cant build without element');
        return;
 }

  var container = this.el.nativeElement;
  var inst = jQuery(container);
  var targetElement = inst.find('#output');

  if (!targetElement){
    console.log('cant find the pivot element');
    return;
  }


 while (targetElement.firstChild){
    targetElement.removeChild(targetElement.firstChild);
  }

  //here is the magic
  targetElement.pivot([
        {color: "blue", shape: "circle"},
        {color: "red", shape: "triangle"}
    ],
    {
        rows: ["color"],
        cols: ["shape"]
     });
  }
 }
```

**--pivot-wrapper.component.html**

```
 <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I think there is a typo here, you wanted to include the "pivot.css" instead of the .js file in  "styles": [
     "../node_modules/pivottable/dist/pivot.min.js", right?

Comment: also in               "node_modules/jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui.min.js",

Answer (score 0):

I think it ll be of help to someone dealing with pivot table where there is no css being loaded. 
I didn't realize that I forgot to include `pivot table css` in `angular-cli.json`:

[image]